Who closes my session and how can I avoid it when using same session on reading/inserting into a domain object?
I have a Spring job what retrieves some data from db using hibernate (only once per job) and uses this data to insert in db other data ,still using hibernate.
I have a session object that I try to pass from CustomJobExecutionListener to my Writer class in a SpringBatchJob, to use the same session for read and for inserting, in order to not have this org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions;.
With the current setup , the session gets closed:
ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper - PooledConnection has already been closed.

If I keep the same code, but not call session.flush() , no exception occurs but nothing gets written in db.
This is the job setup:
    <batch:partition step="customLoadFile" partitioner="customFilePartitioner">
        <batch:handler grid-size="8" task-executor="customJobTaskExecutor"/>
    </batch:partition>
</batch:step>

<batch:step id="customLoadFile">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="customTransactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="customFileReader" writer="customFileWriter" commit-interval="5"/>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

<bean id="customFileWriter" class="com.example.batch.CustomItemWriter">
    <property name="customService" ref="customService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customJobExecutionListener" class="com.example.batch.CustomJobExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="customFileWriter"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="customSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

where
public class CustomJobExecutionListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    private final CustomItemWriter customItemWriter;
    private final SessionFactory customSessionFactory;

    public CustomJobExecutionListener(CustomItemWriter customItemWriter, SessionFactory customSessionFactory) {
        this.customItemWriter = customItemWriter;
        this.customSessionFactory = customSessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        Session session = customSessionFactory.openSession();
        customItemWriter.populateDataFromDb(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {}
}

public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CustomLogModel> {

    private CustomService customService;
    private Session session;

    private void populateDataFromDb(Session session) {
        this.session = session;

        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        System.out.println("Retrieving all db info.");

        List<Object[]> data = customService.getAllData(session);

        data.forEach(record -> {
            ArticleDomain articleSupplement = (ArticleDomain) record[2];
            // Do something with articleSupplement
        });

        stopWatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Finished retrieving data.");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CustomLogModel> items) throws Exception {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        for (CustomLogModel item : items) {
            customService.insertData(item, findArticleDomainByFileName(fileName), session);
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Finished inserting data for a batch of " + items.size() + " items.");
    }

    private ArticleDomain findArticleDomainByFileName       // Implementation here
    }

    public void setCustomService(CustomService customService) {
        this.customService = customService;
    }
}

public class CustomService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Object[]> getAllData(Session session) {
        List<Object[]> dbData = session.createQuery("select i.fileName, i.date, a " + "from ArticleDomain a " + "left join fetch a.ipList i ")
                .list();
        return dbData;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void insertData(CustomLogModel logModel, ArticleDomain articleDomain, Session session) {
        try {
            if (articleDomain.ipList && !articleDomain.ipList.empty) {
                articleDomain?.ipList?.last()?.isLast = false;
            }

            def ipRecord = new IpRecord(articleId: logModel.articleId,
                    fileName: logModel.fileName,
                    failReason: supplementsLogModel.failReason,
                    ...);

            articleDomain.addToIpList(ipRecord);
            session.save(articleSupplement);
            session.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error", ex);
        }
    }
}


An ArticleDomain object will have a list of IpRecords, each IpRecord can have same fileName, but process date different

As the exception indicates, there are two concurrent sessions for the same collection, leading to conflicts as the connection has already been closed from another session.
This is because you're manually handling the Hibernate session while also using the @Transactional annotation, which causes Spring to open an additional session under the hood. I suggest keeping the @Transactional annotation and letting the Spring framework to manage transactions and sessions automatically. Additionally, you need to define Spring JPA repositories e.g. ArticleDomainRepository to persist your entities like ArticleDomain instead of managing Hibernate's sessions manually.
The code could be modified as follows:
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CustomLogModel> {
    @Autowired
    private CustomService customService;

    private void populateDataFromDb(Session session) {
    
      StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
      stopWatch.start();
      System.out.println("Retrieving all db info.");

      List<Object[]> data = customService.getAllData(session);

       data.forEach(record -> {
           ArticleDomain articleSupplement = (ArticleDomain) record[2];
          ....
       });

       stopWatch.stop();
       System.out.println("Finished retrieving data.");
    }

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends CustomLogModel> items) throws Exception {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();
    for (CustomLogModel item : items) {
     customService.insertData(item, findArticleDomainByFileName(fileName), session);
    }
    stopWatch.stop();
    System.out.println("Finished inserting data for a batch of " + items.size() + " items.");
    }
  ....
}

@Service
public class CustomService {

  @Autowired
  private ArticleDomainRepository articleDomainRepository;

  @Autowired
  private IpRecordRepository ipRecordRepository;

  @Transactional
  public void insertData(CustomLogModel logModel, ArticleDomain articleDomain) {
    .....
    articleDomainRepository.save(articleDomain);
}

}

for the insert method I don't want it to be transactional because if 1 entry from a batch of 10 (let's say) fails, I want the other 9 to still be persisted in db.

If you don't want to be transactional, remove the @Transactiinal annotation. Spring still handles the Hibernate sessions under the hood automatically.

@ gkatiforis  I did that after seeing your note, now I receive Message: nested transactions not supported , in writer I have: ```public void write(List<? extends CustomLogModel> items) throws Exception {
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()
for (SupplementsLogModel item : items) {
dbService.insertSupplementsInfoForProcessedArticles(item,findArticleSupplementByFileName(fileName), session)
}
}
    session.flush()
    tx.commit()
    session.clear()```

and in the service i just removed @Trasactional.

As it is mentioned in the answer, remove the transactions and session management from your code. Spring JPA handles the sessions automatically for you.

If I don't pass the same session used for reading to the insert method, even without any @Transaction annotation, I receive Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Seems like a forever fight

Remove session completely from your code and let Spring manage the sessions.

I know it may be frustrating, that's what I did , no session passed to no method, in read i do ArticleDomain.withSession{ session ->... session.createQuery(hqlQuery).list()}, and in write method and  customService.insertData(item, findArticleDomainByFileName(fileName) I dont have anything about a seesiun, I only do articleDomain.save(flush: true) but it gives me Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

You need to define Spring JPA repositories e.g. ArticleDomainRepository to persist your entities like ArticleDomain instead of managing Hibernate's sessions manually. Answer updated accordingly.

What helped me was to not split the input file, nor to have customFilePartitioner. So just these steps: pull the file and then process it (using reader, writer as before), just not having a grid size of 8, not multiple splitted files. In this way, no need to pass session object to read data/ insert data methods.
